# How to use custom routes in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, custom-routes

I want to implement custom routes in CakePHP. I am following the docs

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes

My custom route in `app/Routing/Route`

```
<?php

App::uses('CakeRoute', 'lib/Cake/Routing/Route');

class CategoryRoute extends CakeRoute
{
    public function parse($url)
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url);
        if (empty($params)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

`app/Config/routes.php`

```
App::uses('CategoryRoute', 'Routing/Route');
Router::connect('/mypage/*', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'view'), ['routeClass' => 'CategoryRoute']);
```

but I get

```
Missing Controller

Error: Controller could not be found.

Error: Create the class Controller below in file: app/Controller/Controller.php
```

When I remove `['routeClass' => 'CategoryRoute']`, rerouting just works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look at the API documenation: **[API > CakeRoute::parse()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-CakeRoute.html#_parse)**

The `parse()` method is supposed to return an array of parsed parameters (ie `$params`) on success, or `false` on failure.